# Fancybox iframe close button not hidden when showCloseButton is set to 'false'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, user-interface, iframe, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 1.3.4 with jQuery 1.6.2

When I call the following fancybox function to load an html page in an iframe, everything loads fine, and there are no errors:

```
$.fancybox({
    'width'             : '75%',
    'height'            : '75%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'              : 'search.htm'
});
```

When I add the `showCloseButton` option everything loads fine, and there are no errors **BUT** the close button is stil shown:

```
$.fancybox({
    'width'             : '75%',
    'height'            : '75%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'              : 'search.htm',
    'showCloseButton'   : 'false'
});
```

How can I get rid of the corner box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, saw the problem as soon as the StackOverflow syntax highlighting appeared. No quote marks on `false`

```
$.fancybox({
    'width'             : '75%',
    'height'            : '75%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'              : 'search.htm',
    'showCloseButton'   : false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue despite following the documentation that comes up as first result in Google.

Turns out the API changed, and the docs are outdated. See v2 docs:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

---

Use the `closeBtn` property instead:

```
jQuery.fancybox({
    closeBtn: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   showCloseButton:'hide'
```